# iOS Simulator resetting an image iteratively

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, iteration, simulator

I'm currently developing an app that will reset an image iteratively, and the future images can not be stored or predicted. For simple tests, I used

```
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mountain.jpg"];
image = [ /* function that changes image */ ];
self.imageView.image = image
```

and this worked fine. The `imageView` updated, just like I wanted. But when I do

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++){
    image = [ /* function that changes image */ ];
    self.imageView.image = image;
 }
```

it doesn't work. So I tried this:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%d", i);
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
    image = [self.brain recontructImage:image iterations:10];
    self.imageView.image = image;
    [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.imageView setImage:image];
}
```

and flipped it so the `[self.image setNeedsDisplay]` and `[self.image setImage:image]` where before the `image = [ /* function that changes image */ ]`.

I've only tried this in the simulator, and I'm beginning to wonder if it's broken, but I doubt it. Maybe it's an issue with timing, but I paused for a second. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this a typo? should you not be using self.imageView and not self.image ??

Comment: Whoops. I copied and pasted from my code, and my `imageView` was just called `image`. I'll edit it.